# Como guardar una imagen en Android sin comprimirla?

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion Android que captura imagenes y las guarda en la memoria interna, pero al guardarlas las imagenes se comprimen y yo quiero qque se guarden en tamaño original sin ningun tipo de comprension.

este es el codigo que estoy utilizando para guardar las imagenes, como hago para que no me las comprima??

```
public File saveToInternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap bitmapImage) {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);

        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        File mypath = new File(directory, "TheChat" + (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) + "Avatar.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return mypath;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar la imagen sin comprimirla, simplemente guarda en formato .png, en el cual no aplica la compresión y claro, definir calidad 100% :

```
bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream );
```